# How to make Rails 4.2 work with Postgres Jsonb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've seen a few [blog](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/211-interesting-rails-4-2-changes) [posts](http://lengarvey.github.io/rails42_roro/#7)  claiming that rails 4.2 added support for the new Jsonb data type in Postgres 4.2.

However, googling gets me zero results on how to actually use the datatype. Since I'm not depending on key order and I would like my application to be fast, I would very much like to use Jsonb instead of json in one of my models.

Was it actually added in 4.2, and, if so, how do you use it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's part of the not yet released version of Rails 4.2 (currently 4.2.0.rc3). To use the datatype, specify the `jsonb` type when creating a table:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.jsonb :extra_info
end
```

or add to an existing table

```
add_column :users, :extra_info, :jsonb
```

Since `jsonb` is *virtually* the same as `json` except for the internal storage, [the way you work with the column](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) is the same as well.

Comment: There are a number of operators made possible in Postgres 9.4. Checkout this article on some of those in the context of a Rails 4.2 app. http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/