# Use where queries in JSONB datatype in Rails Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

How to query out schedules who has slot_details which have empty appointment_id. Here is an example data set:

```
    id: 98,
  consulting_location_doctor_id: 498,
  schedule_date: Thu, 15 Jan 2015 00:00:00 IST +05:30,
  slot_details:
   [{"end"=>"2015-01-15T15:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T14:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:30 pm to  3:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T15:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T15:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:00 pm to  3:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T16:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T15:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:30 pm to  4:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T16:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T16:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:00 pm to  4:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T17:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T16:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:30 pm to  5:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T17:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T17:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:00 pm to  5:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T18:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T17:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:30 pm to  6:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T18:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T18:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:00 pm to  6:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T19:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T18:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:30 pm to  7:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T19:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T19:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:00 pm to  7:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T20:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T19:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:30 pm to  8:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T20:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T20:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 8:00 pm to  8:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T21:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T20:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 8:30 pm to  9:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T21:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T21:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:00 pm to  9:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T22:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T21:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:30 pm to 10:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T22:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T22:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:00 pm to 10:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T23:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T22:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:30 pm to 11:00 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-15T23:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T23:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:00 pm to 11:30 pm", appointment_id: ""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-16T00:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-15T23:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:30 pm to 12:00 am", appointment_id: ""}],
  start_and_end_time: Thu, 15 Jan 2015...Fri, 16 Jan 2015,
  deleted_at: nil,
  deleted_by_id: nil,
  created_at: Tue, 30 Dec 2014 04:28:06 IST +05:30,
  updated_at: Tue, 30 Dec 2014 04:28:06 IST +05:30>
```

I tried the example in [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) as well. There is no example for where query on array of json. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Rails 4.2 work with Postgres Jsonb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462929/how-to-make-rails-4-2-work-with-postgres-jsonb)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using JSON for this? Your `slot_details` looks to be very consistently structured, a separate table would probably be a better idea.

Comment: @muistooshort I decided to go with this structure because. The row you see is for a single day for a single consulting_location of a doctor. A doctor can has many such consulting_location each having multiple slots for a single day. If I bring this out as a seperate table, won't become too big very soon?

Comment: Also the question has not been answered before, I have tried the solution there and it was not helpful. There was no pointers as to how to query array of json.

Comment: How would it be bigger as a separate table than as embedded JSON? I'd guess that it would be smaller, faster, easier to work with, and have access to a richer set of data types. You could even set up proper integrity constraints.

Comment: If one doctor has two consulting locations and each has 300 working days and if each working day has 10 slots then we have 3000 slots rows in total for a single doctor. Is that not big considering that there will be hundreds of doctors who can have multiple consulting locations or is that fine. I accept that it can hold a richer data set

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, your slot_details is a json column? And you want to query to find those rows that have an empty appointment id or are you looking for those empty elements within the array?

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I am looking for empty element in the array of json. THat is, empty `appointment_id`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
slot -> 'slot_details' @> '[{"end"=>"2015-01-15T20:00:00.000+00:00"}]'
```

the idea is to ask if the partial subarray contained. If you were not in an array bun in an object it would instead be (let say we have a profile object):

```
profile -> 'basics' @> '{"name":"john"}'
```

don't be fooled trying to use `?` here instead of `@>`